Ember.js octane acceptance test
I don't understand why fillIn can't find 'data-test-code-nav-selector'.
I have paused the test and using the devtools I copied this DOM excerpt. It displays as expected. As you can see, the select tag has the expected attribute.
<select label="codingDropdown" class="h-full bg-gray-50 rounded shadow border py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" data-test-code-nav-selector="">
    <option value="PDF_I10_PCS_APPENDICES">ICD-10 PCS Appendices</option>
    <option value="PDF_I10_PCS_REFERENCE_MANUAL">ICD-10-PCS Reference Manual</option>
</select>

Then, in the test.js file, I'm calling fillIn with the same attribute.
await this.pauseTest();
fillIn('data-test-code-nav-selector', 'PDF_I10_PCS_REFERENCE_MANUAL');

But the test server states:
global failure: Error: Element not found when calling `fillIn('data-test-code-nav-selector')`.@ 10974 ms
Source:     
Error: Element not found when calling `fillIn('data-test-code-nav-selector')`.

The Ember.js forum states: ask your question on stackoverflow.

Also worth knowing the discord server has a great community.

I think you want:
await fillIn('[data-test-code-nav-selector]', 'PDF_I10_PCS_REFERENCE_MANUAL');

note the square brackets around the attribute -- uses the same syntax as CSS selectors.

Ah, thank you. I suspect this will NOT the be the last time that I forget to use the []'s.
